# checking EOF on unix cp program

Tags: unix, operating-system, system-calls

I'm writing a unix cp program, but I'm unclear about checking for EOF. The code I have is:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int in, out;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (argc != 3)
        cout << "Error: incorrect number of params" << endl;
    if ((in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0666)) == -1)
        cout << "Error: cannot open input file" << endl;
    if ((out = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1)
        cout << "Cannot create output file" << endl;
    else
        while ((read(in, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
            write(out, buf, BUFFER_SIZE);


    return 0;
}
```

It reads and writes fine, but writes past EOF when writing the output file. So I get a couple lines of gibberish past the end of the file. Am I just not checking for EOF correctly? I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the man page for the `read` function.

On end-of-file, `read` returns `0`. It returns `-1` only if there's an error.

`read` can read fewer bytes than you asked to (and it must do so if there aren't that many bytes remaining to be read). Your `write` call assumes that `read` actually read `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes.

You need to save the result returned by `read` and write only that many bytes -- and you need to terminate the loop when `read` returns `0` (indicating end-of-file) or `-1` (indicating an error). In the latter case, you should probably do something to handle the error, or at least inform the user.

---

Incidentally, you don't need the `0666` mode argument when calling `open` to open the file for reading; that applies only with `O_CREAT`. Since `open` is actually a *variadic* function (like `printf`), you don't have to supply all the arguments.

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) is not clear on this point; it pretends that there are two different forms of the `open` function:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

but in fact that's not legal in C. The [POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) correctly shows the declaration as:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I missed the return value of read() when I was reading the man pages. Also, the 0666 param fixed an annoying default file permissions error I was getting when I tried to check my output file